# Why doesn't mapping over a Try remove the Try in this case

Tags: scala

```
// redis.get(key) returns a Option[A]

redis.get(key).map(x => Try(x.toInt)).map(counter => doSomething(counter))
```

I am getting an error because doSomething wants an Int but I am passing a Try[Int].

I thought mapping on the Try would remove it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're mapping the `Option`, and not the `Try`.

Comment: My first map is the option[A], then my second one is the Try isnt' it?

Comment: You're mapping an `Option[A]` to an `Option[Try[Int]]`.

Comment: What is your desired resulting type of this whole expression? Even with correct parenthesis, you'll get an `Option[Try[Int]]`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parens in the wrong place.  As Michael Zajac said, you're mapping the `Option`, not the `Try`.

Fixed:

```
redis.get(key).map(x => Try(x.toInt).map(counter => doSomething(counter)))
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW You can also write above expression like this. Try will catch exceptions for you.

```
Try(redis.get(key).get.toInt)
```